# Add a comma to the beginning of each line in python

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I have a "JSON" file that is improperly formatted. It is set up in a compressed state

```
[{ a bunch of info} 
 { a bunch of info2} 
 { a bunch of info3}]
```

My plan is to use python to add a "," to the beginning of each line to return this file to proper JSON format. I believe that I need to do something like:

```
for line in file:
    line += ","
```

Its the action inside the for loop that is getting me.

Thanks

Comment: If it is one time operation you could simple use an editor with multi-cursor support https://tahoeninjas.blog/2019/03/30/multi-cursor-editing-in-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0):

Use regex replace.

```py
import re

s = '''[{ a bunch of info} 
 { a bunch of info2} 
 { a bunch of info3}]'''

o = re.sub(r'}(\s*){', r'},\1{', s)
print(o)
```

```
# [{ a bunch of info},
#  { a bunch of info2},
#  { a bunch of info3}]
```